# how to convert a frame of video to image in ipad/safari with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, video, safari

I tried to save a frame of video as a picture in ipad/safari with javascript.

But as far as I know, the method with canvas(drawImage) is unavailable.
Like this:

```js
var video=document.querySelector('video');
const canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width=video.videoWidth;
canvas.height=video.videoHeight;
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

It does not work.

Reason From [Apple Drawimage Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/canvasrenderingcontext2d/1630282-drawimage): The image object can be an img element, a canvas element, or a video element. **Use of the video element is not supported in Safari on iOS, however.**

And from [Safari HTML5 Canvas Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/HTML-canvas-guide/DrawingImages/DrawingImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010542-CH5-SW7): For a description of how to use video as an image source, see **Putting Video on Canvas.**

But there is no link about *Putting Video on Canvas.*.

Therefore, how to do it? I'm very confused.